# Undo `git config` command

Tags: windows, git, cmd

How can I undo this command
`git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

Comment: What did you want to set it to?

Comment: `git config --global --unset ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More precisely, for that specific key, using [`git config --unset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---unset)

```
git config --global --unset url."git@github.com:".insteadOf
```

`url."git@github.com:".insteadOf` is the key to unset.